Close disk authentication window without user input using Python on macOS
I’m trying to close this window on a dual boot system using Python, but I’m having trouble identifying the name and PID of the process and then executing the script with sudo privileges. Quitting the authd process, as per the code below seems to work but, I’m still stuck with the authentication issue.
I found some similar topics and they helped me to simplify the code, but none of them really solved the problem and now I'm at my wits end. I'd like to avoid installing additional packages like psutil if at all possible.
So I’m looking at two Python solutions I can think of:

Modify the script so that it can quit the authd process (or the correct process) without user input
Bring the window into focus and press Esc key (or Cancel button)

I had to abandon the second solution, as I couldn't figure it out at all, but it would be preferable, because the window can be dismissed by pressing the physical Esc key and, no elevated privileges are needed.
But if anyone has a better idea I’ll be happy to try it.
I'm running macOS Sequoia with Python 3.9.6

    import os
    import subprocess
    import signal
    
    def kill_process_pid(name):
        child = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
        response = child.communicate()[0]
        thepid = [int(pid) for pid in response.split()][0]
        os.kill(thepid, signal.SIGTERM)

    killit = kill_process_pid("authd")

